# Links in EXM emails are broken for some users

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-ecm, sitecore-exm

We experience the following problem: when we send an email via EXM, links inside the email body doesn't work for some users.

Links inside email body are always converted by default to something like:

```
http://domainname/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_contact_id=xxxx84B137D2037C7D180&ec_message_id=xxxxB4CEAA3FD1A3B&ec_url=%2fthelinkpath
```

that is obviously done for tracking reasons.

However, some users experience 404 error when navigate the link. The Log always says the following:

```
ERROR EmailCampaign: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Analytics
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.StandardSession.InitializePage(ICurrentPageContext currentPageContext, ICurrentPageContext oldPage)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.StandardSession.Identify(String userName)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines.RedirectUrl.IdentifyContact.Process(RedirectUrlPipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.UI.RedirectUrlPage.HandleMessageEvent(ID messageId, ID contactId)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.UI.MessageEventPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

The only way to fix this error for the user is to clear his cookies or use another browser or use incognito mode. The user is currently logged out from the website.

Sitecore version 8.0 + EXM

Has anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: do you have any IP address restrictions set in any Sitecore config files? E.g not to track any visits from dev team or marketing team?

Comment: This is a known bug and can/will happen if you currently have a session where you're identified as another user. It will be fixed in the next release of EXM. I believe the easiest solution for you would be to replace the pipeline processor with your own and handle the exception (that will be thrown by Sitecore.Analytics)

Comment: @Tchami I know this is a long time ago, but do you know if this fix was ever made and in which version of EXM please?  We're using v3.4 (build 161028) and are seeing a similar problem. Thanks.

Comment: @WheretheresaWill I'm not sure. What you can try is moving the IdentifyContact processor of the redirectUrl pipeline in front of the RegisterMessageEvent processor

Comment: Okay @Tchami I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, this is because of cookies stored from previous sessions, thanks Tchami.

Sitecore Support answer was the same:

> This error occurs when you open multiple mails with multiple
>   contactId's in the same browser.

But they didn't propose any solution except for clearing cookies or using another browser.

However, we don't want to break user experience even for this rarely appeared cases.

So, in order to handle the exception, we have found that the following pipeline processor should be rewritten:

```
<processor type ="Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines.RedirectUrl.IdentifyContact, Sitecore.EmailCampaign" />
```

You can have a look at the code of custom processor [here](https://chebalt.wordpress.com/2016/05/10/broken-links-in-exm-emails).